# How do I calculate a time taken to upload a file using flask

Tags: flask, file-upload

I want to calculate the time taken to upload a file using flask. I have started the timer in the before_request method and trying to end it in after_request, using time.monotonic. But the time taken to upload the same file is different every time.Are the before and after request methods the right places to start and end?

```
@app.before_request
def before_request():
    global  request_start_time
    request_start_time = time.monotonic()
    print(request_start_time)

@app.after_request
def after_request(response):
    global end_time
    global duration, b
    end_time = time.monotonic()
    duration = end_time - request_start_time
    print("speed:", b/duration/100000)
    return response

@app.route('/upload')
def upload():
    return render_template('upload.html')


@app.route('/uploader', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def uploader():

    global duration,b
    if request.method == 'POST':
        f = request.files['file']
        print("uploader")
        f.save(secure_filename(f.filename))
        b = os.path.getsize(f.filename)
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you believe the upload duration would be identical each and every time?  What kind of differences are you seeing?

Comment: There is a huge difference in the duration every time. I'm trying to calculate file upload speed, using duration and the speed is coming up to 300MBps which seems unusual using my network